# Progress DB 4GL and ODBC data extract

Tags: odbc, extract, progress-4gl

I am trying to connect to Progress DB 4GL to extract data using ODBC (Qlikview).

Is is possible to extract data using 4GL via ODBC?

Can you please guide me on this?

Thanks and Regards,
Silambarasan

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Qlikview to Progress via ODBC and SQL is relatively straight-forward.  What is driving the "using 4GL" part of things?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use the Progress SQL92 interface via ODBC to access 4GL tables (CRUD for records), but you cannot create or amend 4GL tables using SQL92.

Any tables you create using SQL92 CREATE TABLE command, cannot be seen by 4GL/ABL programs.

The Progress website says that the Progress ODBC driver is included in the Progress/Openedge client package.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try the option and will share you the results. I just wonder if we have an option to use 4GL queries to retrieve data from databases using any of the connectors like ODBC/OLEDB.  Can you guide me the options if we have.

Comment: Creating tables is not needed to extract data.

Comment: @carlverbiest - agreed - I was just commenting on the limitations of the progress SQL92 engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the included ODBC driver but that uses SQL syntax, not ABL (4GL) queries.

Progress Datadirect has a product that offers an ODBC frontend for OpenEdge Appserver https://documentation.progress.com/output/DataDirect/openaccessbooks/oaoeguide.pdf

http://acorn.ro/products/abl-jdbc/ offers a jdbc interface to ABL code.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC clients talk SQL, not 4GL.

To use the 4GL to extract data you use either a "self service" (shared memory) connection if you are on the same host as the server, or you can use a "client networking" license if you are on a network connected computer.

You could, of course, go through all sorts of convoluted stuff to use the 4GL without an actual db connection and a series of intermediate layers to somehow get an ODBC data connection.  (You  could, for instance, use sockets to communicate with a C# app that uses ODBC to connect to  Progress...)  But the specifics would depend on what you have available, what your coding skills are and **why** you are trying to do this.

If you were to manage to cobble together something like that you would still have the problem that the ODBC connection speaks SQL.  So if you are expecting features like 4GL index selection or triggers or "variable width data everywhere" to work you are going to be out of luck.  The SQL interface is ignorant of those things and won't be able to provide them.

I'm pretty sure that Clikview doesn't talk 4GL at all -- so you would also have to convert from 4GL back to SQL again.  The whole thing makes no real sense.

(Regarding "why" I can only imagine that you are attempting to bypass a licensing requirement.  If that is the case then you are not only making this much, much more difficult than it needs to be but you are also not going to solve the licensing problem.  The license doesn't care what technologies and products are, or are not, used to make connections.)